# check multiple cells value in a sorted list have same value as another manual cell

Tags: excel-formula

How to write a formula in excel that based on critria it can check if list of multiple result cells have same value.

I attached example:

1. Look for all cell with the number 100
2. Verify that the list of these cells contain same date value of one cell.
   [image]

I try to use formula such as: COUNTIF + INDEX and MATCH but didn't work as expacted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you can use `=ROWS(FILTER(....))` but what I would do is create a hidden column that evaluates it per row, maybe with something like

```
=IF(A2="","",XLOOKUP(A2,A$2:A,B$2:B)=B2)
```

and copy that formula down the column.

This way, you can not only see if there are any bad values (by COUNTIFS for false values where the A-column's value matches the "find these cells" value) but apply conditional formatting as well to highlight the bad values.